# How do I make a file/project files tree view in C#

Tags: c#, filetree

I wish to make a program that will create a project that will have various sub folders. The only problem is that I don't have an idea how to start with it. We have not covered this in college.

If you could point me to a tutorial, explain how or give me some kind of start I would be happy.

EDIT:
The basic idea is that I am going to make a program that will save a 'world', for which you can add races, magic, religion, et cetera. These will come in the sub menu then.

Comment: these folders what should contain ?

Comment: I would suggest giving it a try first and then post back with your code and the issues you are having.   As far as a tutorial, open your web browser, go to google and type in C# treeview Example or tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are the UI aspect, data aspect and storage aspect of your question. If you are just concern about the UI aspect, you can use either Windows Forms or WPF, both have TreeView controls for you to do that. If you are just concern about the data aspect, then you basically create a few classes/struct to maintain parent/child nodes. If you are concern about the storage aspect, you can take a look of XML.